# ZoneSharding combined with Index usage

Tags: mongodb, indexing, query-optimization, sharding, zone

i have a question regarding optimized querying in Zone Sharded System

Lets make an example first:
You have two Zones A and B
In the collection there are 3 fields
{*Zone*: string, *Lotnumber*: string, *LotAttributeA*: string}
The ShardKey contains  { *Zone*:1, *Lotnumber*:1}
On the field *LotAttribute* there is only a regular index

Now you want to query for a specific *LotAttribute*.
If you query for *LotAttribute* only, it will result in a scatter gather query and it will be sent out to all shards.

If you now query for   *Zone*:"A" and *LotAttribute* it would be very nice, if MongoDB would do the following. Go to all Shards which belong to ZoneA and then use the LotAttribute Index on the just filtered shards.

But what currently happen is that MongoDB decided if it is more efficient to use the (partially queried) ShardKey OR the index. But never a combination of them.

Does anybody know if there is a way to "force" MongoDB to got for the "nice way" mentioned above?

Thanks for your help!

@Wernfried Domscheit:
Additional Info:
I know that the shardkey is indexed. But my use case is that i cannot use the whole ShardKey to get the wanted data. I just know the *Zone*  and the *LotAttribute*. Each index is not good on its own, but together they would be great (--> Use first part (Zone) of the Shard Key to find the Zone and inside the Zone use the *LotAttribute* Index to get the data ). It is hard to explain, i hope you know what i mean.

Comment: The shard key is always also indexed, so I don't get your question.

Comment: Try index hint?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding right, your central question is why the mongos does not  limit the query to shards holding the desired zone.

It actually does this.

To demonstrate why you are probably seeing it touch more than one shard, I created a sharded collection like this:

```
sh.shardCollection("test.zonetest",{zone:1, lot:1})
```

Assigned each shard to a zone:

```
sh.addShardToZone("shard01","A")
sh.addShardToZone("shard02","B")
sh.addShardToZone("shard03","C")
```

And defined some ranges:

```
sh.updateZoneKeyRange("test.zonetest",{zone:"A",lot:MinKey()},{zone:"A",lot:MaxKey()},"A")
sh.updateZoneKeyRange("test.zonetest",{zone:"B",lot:MinKey()},{zone:"B",lot:MaxKey()},"B")
sh.updateZoneKeyRange("test.zonetest",{zone:"C",lot:MinKey()},{zone:"C",lot:MaxKey()},"C")
```

MongoDB split the collection according to these ranges, created chunks for the spaces in between the ranges, and balanced them to the shards like so:

```
mongos> db.getSiblingDB("config").chunks.find({ns:"test.zonetest"},{_id:0,min:1,shard:1,max:1})
{ "min" : { "zone" : { "$minKey" : 1 }, "lot" : { "$minKey" : 1 } }, "max" : { "zone" : "A", "lot" : { "$minKey" : 1 } }, "shard" : "shard03" }
{ "min" : { "zone" : "A", "lot" : { "$minKey" : 1 } }, "max" : { "zone" : "A", "lot" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } }, "shard" : "shard01" }
{ "min" : { "zone" : "A", "lot" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } }, "max" : { "zone" : "B", "lot" : { "$minKey" : 1 } }, "shard" : "shard02" }
{ "min" : { "zone" : "B", "lot" : { "$minKey" : 1 } }, "max" : { "zone" : "B", "lot" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } }, "shard" : "shard02" }
{ "min" : { "zone" : "B", "lot" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } }, "max" : { "zone" : "C", "lot" : { "$minKey" : 1 } }, "shard" : "shard01" }
{ "min" : { "zone" : "C", "lot" : { "$minKey" : 1 } }, "max" : { "zone" : "C", "lot" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } }, "shard" : "shard03" }
{ "min" : { "zone" : "C", "lot" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } }, "max" : { "zone" : { "$maxKey" : 1 }, "lot" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } }, "shard" : "shard01" }
```

As you can see from the chunk ranges, a document with a zone of "A" could be on either shard01 or shard02, and zone "C" could be on shard01 or shard03.

When I query as you described using `.explain("executionStats"), it shows that the mongos actually does only send the query to the 2 shards that could possibly have the zone value I was querying:
(If anyone knows the markdown formatting magic to make this collapsible, please let me know)

```
    "executionStats" : {
        "nReturned" : 1653,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 13,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 1653,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 1653,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "SHARD_MERGE",
            "nReturned" : 1653,
            "executionTimeMillis" : 13,
            "totalKeysExamined" : 1653,
            "totalDocsExamined" : 1653,
            "totalChildMillis" : NumberLong(7),
            "shards" : [
                {
                    "shardName" : "shard01",
                    "executionSuccess" : true,
                    "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "SHARDING_FILTER",
                        "nReturned" : 0,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works" : 2,
                        "advanced" : 0,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 0,
                        "restoreState" : 0,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "chunkSkips" : 0,
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "FETCH",
                            "filter" : {
                                "attr" : {
                                    "$eq" : "attr10"
                                }
                            },
                            "nReturned" : 0,
                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                            "works" : 1,
                            "advanced" : 0,
                            "needTime" : 0,
                            "needYield" : 0,
                            "saveState" : 0,
                            "restoreState" : 0,
                            "isEOF" : 1,
                            "docsExamined" : 0,
                            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                            "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "nReturned" : 0,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                                "works" : 1,
                                "advanced" : 0,
                                "needTime" : 0,
                                "needYield" : 0,
                                "saveState" : 0,
                                "restoreState" : 0,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                    "zone" : 1,
                                    "lot" : 1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "zone_1_lot_1",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                    "zone" : [ ],
                                    "lot" : [ ]
                                },
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : false,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 2,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                    "zone" : [
                                        "[\"C\", \"C\"]"
                                    ],
                                    "lot" : [
                                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "keysExamined" : 0,
                                "seeks" : 1,
                                "dupsTested" : 0,
                                "dupsDropped" : 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "shardName" : "shard03",
                    "executionSuccess" : true,
                    "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "SHARDING_FILTER",
                        "nReturned" : 1653,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works" : 1654,
                        "advanced" : 1653,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 14,
                        "restoreState" : 14,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "chunkSkips" : 0,
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "FETCH",
                            "filter" : {
                                "zone" : {
                                    "$eq" : "C"
                                }
                            },
                            "nReturned" : 1653,
                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                            "works" : 1654,
                            "advanced" : 1653,
                            "needTime" : 0,
                            "needYield" : 0,
                            "saveState" : 14,
                            "restoreState" : 14,
                            "isEOF" : 1,
                            "docsExamined" : 1653,
                            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                            "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "nReturned" : 1653,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                                "works" : 1654,
                                "advanced" : 1653,
                                "needTime" : 0,
                                "needYield" : 0,
                                "saveState" : 14,
                                "restoreState" : 14,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                    "attr" : 1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "attr_1",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                    "attr" : [ ]
                                },
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : false,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 2,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                    "attr" : [
                                        "[\"attr10\", \"attr10\"]"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "keysExamined" : 1653,
                                "seeks" : 1,
                                "dupsTested" : 0,
                                "dupsDropped" : 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

If you notice, all of the inter-zone chunks are bounded by MinKey and MaxKey, like `{zone:"A", lot:MaxKey()}` to `{zone:"B", lot:MinKey()}`.
This means that if you can exclude these min/max values from the query, the mongos will not consider that chunk when targeting the shards.

In my sample data set, I used string values for the `lot` field.  Since MongoDB query operators are type-sensitive, the predicate `{$gte:""}` will match all string values, and no other type.  You might use `{$gte:-Infinity}` to limit to numeric types.

The result is the chunk that contains the MaxKey as the minimum value is no longer considered, and the query become single-shard:

```
    "executionStats" : {
    "nReturned" : 1653,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 12,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 1653,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 1653,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "SINGLE_SHARD",
            "nReturned" : 1653,
            "executionTimeMillis" : 12,
            "totalKeysExamined" : 1653,
            "totalDocsExamined" : 1653,
            "totalChildMillis" : NumberLong(11),
            "shards" : [
            {
                "shardName" : "shard03",
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "executionStages" : {
                    "stage" : "SHARDING_FILTER",
                    "nReturned" : 1653,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                    "works" : 1654,
                    "advanced" : 1653,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 14,
                    "restoreState" : 14,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "chunkSkips" : 0,
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                            "$and" : [
                            {
                                "zone" : {
                                    "$eq" : "C"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "lot" : {
                                    "$gte" : ""
                                }
                            }
                            ]
                        },
                        "nReturned" : 1653,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works" : 1654,
                        "advanced" : 1653,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 14,
                        "restoreState" : 14,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "docsExamined" : 1653,
                        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "nReturned" : 1653,
                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                            "works" : 1654,
                            "advanced" : 1653,
                            "needTime" : 0,
                            "needYield" : 0,
                            "saveState" : 14,
                            "restoreState" : 14,
                            "isEOF" : 1,
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "attr" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "attr_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "attr" : [ ]
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "attr" : [
                                    "[\"attr10\", \"attr10\"]"
                                ]
                            },
                            "keysExamined" : 1653,
                            "seeks" : 1,
                            "dupsTested" : 0,
                            "dupsDropped" : 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ]
        }
},
```

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks a lot for your comprehensive answer. But if i understand the execution plan right, it does exactly what i tried to explain.
1. Step: MongoDB uses the Shard Key to go to all relevant shards where (in your example) zone C is related to 
2. Step: MongoDB does not use "another" index it is just using "fetch" to get all documents where attr:{$eg:"attr10"}. As far as i know, "fetch" means filtering the data after extracting them!

In my case i have hundreds of millions of documents in each zone. And filtering without making use of an index in a zone takes too much time.

Comment: My apologies, I copied the wrong instance of explain, that one I put in originally was before I had inserted any documents, so it took <1ms to determine there were no matches.  I've edited the answer to replace that with the run from where there were actually documents, which shows it used the expected index.

Comment: No idea what i did wrong, but now i get the same result! Thanks again, you really made my day :-D